# Inconsistency between Network object and Igraph object in R

Tags: r, igraph, data-consistency, statnet

I am starting a descriptive network analysis using both **SNA** (statnet suite) and **igraph** in **R**. I was wondering which suite to use to investigate the different properties of my network, since they have slightly different features that make them not fully interchangeable.

Unfortunately, I noticed that the 2 package returns **different results** (for instance, the maximal clique size identified by SNA is 8, while igraph reaches 17!. 
I build the two objects starting from the same edge list, stored as a dataframe. I could use intergraph to reach the same conclusions, but **how do I define which package created the correct network?**

**EDIT**

I have been asked to provide reproducible example. Providing the data would be useless as I would not be able to create a meaningful subsample of them. Unfortunately, they are private data and I cannot disseminate them. Only to give an idea, below I offer the head of my data.frame containing the edgelist named in the code 'fdi.edge.2003', of class 'data.frame'

```
    > dput(head(fdi.edge.2003, 10))
    structure(list(iso_o = c("ARE", "ARE", "ARE", "ARE", "ARE", "ARE", 
    "ARE", "ARE", "ARE", "ARE"), iso_d = c("AUS", "AUT", "BGD", "BHR", 
    "CHE", "CHN", "EGY", "ESP", "FIN", "GBR"), year = c(2003, 2003, 
    2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003), all_num = c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), all_inv_tot = c(200, 298.6, 
    10, 21.1, 16.1, 30, 36.5, 5.6, 24.6, 8), all_inv_avg = c(200, 
    149.3, 10, 7.03333333333333, 16.1, 15, 12.1666666666667, 5.6, 
    24.6, 8), all_job_tot = c(438, 789, 81, 358, 18, 173, 67, 70, 
    40, 77), all_job_avg = c(438, 394.5, 81, 119.333335876465, 18, 
    86.5, 22.3333339691162, 70, 40, 77), greenf_num = c(1, 2, 0, 
    3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1), greenf_inv_tot = c(200, 298.6, 0, 21.1, 
    16.1, 30, 36.5, 5.6, 0, 8), greenf_inv_avg = c(200, 149.300003051758, 
    0, 7.03333330154419, 16.1000003814697, 15, 12.1666669845581, 
    5.59999990463257, 0, 8), greenf_job_tot = c(438, 789, 0, 358, 
    18, 173, 67, 70, 0, 77), greenf_job_avg = c(438, 394.5, 0, 119.333335876465, 18, 86.5, 22.3333339691162, 70, 0, 77), coloc_num = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), coloc_inv_tot = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), coloc_inv_avg = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), coloc_job_tot = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), coloc_job_avg = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), expan_num = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
        expan_inv_tot = c(0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24.6, 0), expan_inv_avg = c(0, 
        0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24.6000003814697, 0), expan_job_tot = c(0, 
        0, 81, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0), expan_job_avg = c(0, 0, 81, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0), no_flow = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), grav_noinv = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0), dist = c(12092.1591796875, 4245.841796875, 3643.56079101562, 
        426.657623291016, 4830.7373046875, 5966.42724609375, 2370.06079101562, 
        5634.66748046875, 4570.3173828125, 5483.74462890625), distw =         c(11543.8054501625, 
        4324.89105693665, 3561.5309768755, 490.192080768776, 4831.20286380844, 
        5975.25361008682, 2447.29938508511, 5605.06845714264, 4638.03680032616, 
        5594.32698249168), contig = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L), comrelig = c(0.00378700019791722, 0.0094410004094243, 
        0.815205037593842, 0.901609003543854, 0.00625500036403537, 
        0.0227760020643473, 0.776296019554138, 0.00387900019995868, 
        0.00279700011014938, 0.0142930001020432), comlang_off = c(0L, 
        0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), comlang_ethno = c(0L, 
        0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), comcol = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 
        1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), colony = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), comleg_pretrans = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), comcur = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), tdiff = c(5.35000038146973, 3, 2, 1, 3, 
        4, 2, 3.5, 2, 4), conflict = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, 0L), smctry = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
        0L), subg = c(3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3), same_reg = c(0, 
        0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), same_inc = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
        0, 1, 1, 1), simil_inc = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)), datalabel =         "fDIMarket data aggregati per origine-destinazione-anno", time.stamp = " 6 Dec         2017 16:07", formats = c("%9s", 
    "%44s", "%9s", "%44s", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%10.0g", "%10.0g", 
    "%10.0g", "%10.0g", "%8.0g", "%10.0g", "%9.0g", "%10.0g", "%9.0g", 
    "%8.0g", "%10.0g", "%9.0g", "%10.0g", "%9.0g", "%8.0g", "%10.0g", 
    "%9.0g", "%10.0g", "%9.0g", "%8.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", 
    "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%12.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", 
    "%12.0g", "%8.0g", "%9.0g", "%8.0g", "%8.0g", "%8.0g", "%9.0g", 
    "%8.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%8.0g", "%9.0g", "%8.0g", "%8.0g", 
    "%9s", "%8.0g", "%8.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%8.0g", 
    "%8.0g", "%9.0g", "%8.0g", "%8.0g", "%8.0g", "%9s", "%9s", "%9s", 
    "%9s", "%8.0g", "%8.0g", "%9s", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", 
    "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9s", "%10.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9s", "%9.0g", 
    "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9s", "%10.0g", 
    "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", 
    "%10.0g", "%10.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%40.0g", 
    "%40.0g", "%10.0g", "%10.0g", "%10.0g", "%10.0g", "%10.0g", "%10.0g", 
    "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%8.0g", "%8.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", 
    "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g", "%9.0g"), types = c(3L, 44L, 3L, 44L, 
    65527L, 65528L, 65526L, 65526L, 65526L, 65527L, 65526L, 65526L, 
    65527L, 65526L, 65527L, 65526L, 65526L, 65527L, 65526L, 65527L, 
    65526L, 65526L, 65527L, 65526L, 65527L, 65530L, 65527L, 65527L, 
    65526L, 65526L, 65526L, 65527L, 65528L, 65526L, 65526L, 65527L, 
    65528L, 65530L, 65527L, 65530L, 65530L, 65530L, 65530L, 65530L, 
    65530L, 65530L, 65530L, 65527L, 65530L, 65529L, 3L, 65530L, 65530L, 
    65530L, 65530L, 65530L, 65530L, 65530L, 65527L, 65530L, 65530L, 
    65530L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 65530L, 65530L, 2L, 65527L, 65527L, 65527L, 
    65527L, 65527L, 65527L, 3L, 65530L, 65527L, 65527L, 2L, 65527L, 
    65527L, 65527L, 65527L, 65527L, 65527L, 3L, 65530L, 65527L, 65527L, 
    65527L, 65526L, 65530L, 65530L, 65530L, 65529L, 65530L, 65530L, 
    65530L, 65530L, 65530L, 65530L, 65530L, 65526L, 65526L, 65530L, 
    65530L, 65526L, 65526L, 65527L, 65527L, 65530L, 65530L, 65527L, 
    65527L, 65527L, 65527L, 65527L, 65527L, 65527L), val.labels = structure(c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",  "", "", "", "", "gspflag", "gspflag", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), .Names = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",  "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",  "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "gspflag", "gspflag", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")), var.labels = c("iso_3", 
    "Parent Country (Name)", "iso_3", "Host Country (Name)", "Reference year", 
    "Total # of Investments by origin in destination, in reference year", 
    "Total value of investments by origin in destination, in reference year", 
    "Average value of investments flown by origin in destination, in reference year", 
    "Total # of jobs created by year-origin-dest", "Average # of jobs created         by investments by origin in destination, in reference ", 
    "Greenfield - Number of Projects in reference year year", "Greenfield -         Total value by origin in destination, in reference year", 
    "Yearly average value of greenfield projects in the channel", 
    "Greenfield - Total # of jobs by origin in destination, in reference year", 
    "Average # of Jobs created by greenfield projects", "Co-location - Number         of Projects in reference year year", 
    "Co-location - Total value by origin in destination, in reference year", 
    "Yearly average value of co-location projects in the channel", 
    "Co-location - Total # of jobs by origin in destination, in reference year", 
    "Average # of Jobs created by co-location projects", "Greenfield - Number of Projects in reference year year", 
    "Expansion - Total value by origin in destination, in reference year", 
    "Yearly average value of expansion projects in the channel", 
    "Expansion - Total # of jobs by origin in destination, in reference year", 
    "Average # of Jobs created by expansion projects", "Dummy = 1 if no investment in the year-cty_pair observation were recorded", 
    "Only gravity information - no investments. kept for merge with migration", 
    "simple distance (most populated cities, km)", "weighted distance (pop-wt, km)", 
    "Population, total in mn", "GDP (current US$)", "GDP per cap (current US$)", 
    "Area in sq. kms", "Population, total in mn", "GDP (current US$)", 
    "GDP per cap (current US$)", "Area in sq. kms", "1=Contiguity", 
    "1=Common religion", "1=Common official or primary language", 
    "1=Language is spoken by at least 9% of the population", "1=Common colonizer post 1945", 
    "1=Pair ever in colonial relationship", "1=Pair in colonial relationship post 1945", 
    "1=Common legal origins before transition", "1=Common legal origins after transition", 
    "1=Common currency", "nb of hours difference between ex and im", 
    "1=War", "Independence date if colony=1", "hegemon if cursib==1", 
    "1=Origin is current or former hegemon of destination", "1=Destination is current or former hegemon of origin", 
    "1=Trade from heg_o to colony", "1=Trade from colony to heg_d", 
    "1=Pair currently in colonial relationship", "1=Origin is GATT/WTO member", 
    "1=Destination is GATT/WTO member", "= 1 if a BIT ever existed between o and d", 
    "1=RTA (Source: WTO, 2015)", "1=FTA;2=Cust. Union;3=Common Market;4=Economic union (Baier & Bergstrand, 2009)", 
    "1=FTA (Source: Head, Mayer and Ries, 2010)", "origin legal system before transition", 
    "destination legal system before transition", "origin legal system after transition", 
    "destination legal system after transition", "1=ACP to EU", "1=EU to ACP", 
    "Income Category. H=high L=Low etc", "1 if income category = H", 
    "1 if income category = L", "1 if income category = LM", "1 if income category = UM", 
    "1 if fragile state", "1 if small state", "Regional 3-char Code - WB definition", 
    "1 if member of OECD", "1 if country is included among least developed countries", 
    "1 if no information on income level / region is available for FDI parent country", 
    "Income Category. H=high L=Low etc", "1 if income category = H", 
    "1 if income category = L", "1 if income category = LM", "1 if income category = UM", 
    "1 if fragile state", "1 if small state", "Regional 3-char Code - WB definition", 
    "1 if member of OECD", "1 if country is included among least developed countries", 
    "1 if no information on income level / region is available for FDI host country", 
    "simple distance between capitals (capitals, km)", "weighted distance (pop-wt, km) CES distances with theta=-1", 
    "1 if countries were or are the same country", "1=Pair ever in sibling relationship", 
    "1=Pair currently in sibling relationship", "severance year for pairs if sibling == 1", 
    "1=Pair ever in sibling relationship and conflict", "1=Common legal origin changed since transition", 
    "1=Non-reciprocal PTA ; 2=PTA (Source: Baier & Bergstrand, 2009)", 
    "1=Origin is donator", "1=Destination is donator", "report of changes in Rose data", 
    "report of changes in Rose data", "Cost of business start-up procedures (% of GNI per capita)", 
    "Cost of business start-up procedures (% of GNI per capita)", 
    "Start-up procedures to register a business (number)", "Start-up procedures to register a business (number)", 
    "Time required to start a business (days)", "Time required to start a business (days)", 
    "Days+Procs to start a business", "Days+Procs to start a business", 
    "1=Origin is a EU member", "1=Destination is a EU member", "group(iso_o iso_d)", 
    "", "", "", "", "", ""), version = 118L, label.table = structure(list(gspflag = structure(0:3, .Names = c("no gsp recorded in Rose", 
"data directly from Rose", "changes in data from Rose", "Assumption that gsp continues after 1999"))), .Names = "gspflag"), expansion.fields = list(c("no_region_o", "note1", "Following small countries have no information because not independent countries: Anguilla; Christmas Island; Cocos and Keeling Islands; Cook Islands; Falkland Islands; French Guiana; Guadeloupe; Martinique; Montserrat; Netherland Antilles; Niue; Norfolk Island; Pitcairn; Reunion; Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan d..; Saint Pierre and Miquelon; Tokelau; Wallis and Futuna; Western Sahara. notes no_region_o: Serbia and Montenegro has no information Beacuse is treated as separated countries. see variables no_flow and grav_noinv for details"), c("_dta", "note11", "Adesione OECD da fonte OECD "http://www.oecd.org/about/membersandpartners/list-oecd-member-countries.htm\""), c("_dta", "note10", "Classificazione per reddito e definizione fragile-small region Ufficiale World Bank -  \"https://datahelpdesk.worldbank.org/knowledgebase/articles/906519-world-bank-country-and-lending-groups\""
), c("_dta", "note9", "Classificazione reddito e regioni come da WB World Development Indicators"), c("bit", "note1", "It is a dummy that states whether in a certain year there was a BIT between o and d and vice versa."), c("bit", "note0", "1"), c("_dta", "note8", "non ci sono duplicati nel dataset BIT perchè li ho eliminati. In questo modo, per ogni combinazione anno-cty_pair ho una sola osservazione. Mi serve per creare la variabile BIT nel do file principale"), c("_dta", "note7", "South sudan da problemi, è solo come destination country"), c("_dta", "note6", "I seguenti paesi hanno dati gravity ma non di investimenti (vedi variabile invYN e nota connessa). Li possiamo mantenere come cancellare. I paesi in questione sono: Anguilla - Netherland Antilles - Cocos and Keeling Islands - Cook Islands - Christmas Islands - Western Sahara - Falkland Islands - Faeroe Islands - Gibraltar French Guiana Kiribati - Marshall Islands - Northern Mariana Islands - Montserrat - Norfolk Islands - Niue -  Nauru - Pitcairn - Palau - Saint Helena... - San Marino - Saint Pierre et Miquelon  Tokelau - Tonga - Tuvalu - British Virgin Islands - Vanuatu - Wallis and Futuna."), c("_dta", "note5", "geo_dist database scaricato da \"http://www.cepii.fr/CEPII/en/bdd_modele/presentation.asp?id=6\" il 28 febbraio 2017. Updated 10 febbraio 2017"), c("_dta", "note4", "gravity database scaricato da \"http://www.cepii.fr/CEPII/en/bdd_modele/presentation.asp?id=8\" il 28 febbraio 2017. Updated 10 febbraio 2017"), c("gdp_d", "destring", "Characters removed were:"), c("pop_d","destring", "Characters removed were:"), c("gdp_o", "destring", "Characters removed were:"), c("pop_o", "destring", "Characters removed were:"), c("year", "destring", "Characters removed were:"), c("_dta","__JVarLab", "Indicator Name"), c("_dta", "ReS_i", "iso3"), c("_dta", "ReS_ver", "v.2"), c("_dta", "ReS_j", "iso_o"), c("_dta", "ReS_str", "1"), c("_dta", "ReS_Xij", "p"), c("fta_bb", "destring", "Characters removed were:"), c("_dta", "_TSitrvl", "1"), c("_dta", "_TSpanel", "ccode"), 
        c("_dta", "_TStvar", "year"), c("_dta", "_dta", "st"), c("_dta", 
        "st_id", "leadnew"), c("_dta", "st_d", "leadgone"), c("_dta", 
"st_t0", "time0"), c("_dta", "st_t", "tenplus"), c("_dta", 
"_lang_list", "default"), c("_dta", "_lang_c", "default"), 
c("_dta", "st_bs", "1"), c("_dta", "st_s", "1"), c("_dta", 
"st_o", "0"), c("_dta", "st_bd", "failure"), c("_dta", "st_bt", 
"dur8099"), c("_dta", "st_ver", "2"), c("_dta", "tis", "year"
), c("_dta", "iis", "shcode56"), c("_dta", "__xi__Vars__To__Drop__", 
"_Icontnt1_2 _Icontnt1_3 _Icontnt1_4 _Icontnt1_5 _Icontnt1_6 _Icontnt1_7"
), c("_dta", "__xi__Vars__Prefix__", "_I _I _I _I _I _I"), 
c("no_flow", "note1", "Questa variabile mi dice se ho investimenti (=0) nell'osservazione year-cty_pair         oppure se ho solo la coppia paese."
), c("no_flow", "note0", "1"), c("_dta", "note3", "codici ISO (versione 3166 da International Organisation for Standardization - \"https://www.iso.org\""
), c("_dta", "note2", "Investimenti FdiMarket from FDIIntelligence - \"http://www.fdiintelligence.com/\", FDIMarket Database"
), c("_dta", "note1", "Dataset Disaggregato a livello di singola impresa.         Creato da Filippo Santi - Versione: 1 - Data: 9 Nov 2017."
), c("_dta", "note0", "11"), c("no_region_o", "note0", "2"
), c("no_region_o", "note2", "Following small countries have no information because not independent countries:         Anguilla; Christmas Island; Cocos and Keeling Islands; Cook Islands; Falkland Islands; French Guiana; Guadeloupe;         Martinique; Montserrat; Netherland Antilles; Niue; Norfolk Island; Pitcairn; Reunion; Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan d..;         Saint Pierre and Miquelon; Tokelau; Wallis and Futuna; Western Sahara.         notes no_region_o: Serbia and Montenegro has no information Beacuse is treated as separated         countries. see variables no_flow and grav_noinv for details"
), c("no_region_d", "note0", "1"), c("no_region_d", "note1", 
"See notes to no_region_o")), byteorder = "LSF", .Names = c("iso_o", 
    "iso_d", "year", "all_num", "all_inv_tot", "all_inv_avg", "all_job_tot", 
    "all_job_avg", "greenf_num", "greenf_inv_tot", "greenf_inv_avg", 
    "greenf_job_tot", "greenf_job_avg", "coloc_num", "coloc_inv_tot", 
    "coloc_inv_avg", "coloc_job_tot", "coloc_job_avg", "expan_num", 
    "expan_inv_tot", "expan_inv_avg", "expan_job_tot", "expan_job_avg", 
    "no_flow", "grav_noinv", "dist", "distw", "contig", "comrelig", 
    "comlang_off", "comlang_ethno", "comcol", "colony", "comleg_pretrans", 
    "comcur", "tdiff", "conflict", "smctry", "subg", "same_reg", 
    "same_inc", "simil_inc"), n = 228L, row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Below, the code I am using

```
# Create network (STATNET)
library(network)
library(sna)
fdi.net.2003 <- network(fdi.edge.2003, matrix.type = "edgelist",
                        directed = T,
                        ignore.eval = F)
# Computing DIAMETER and APL
# APL and DIAMETER computed in statnet require to compute the geodist
  # inf.replace = 0 substitute distance in unconnected components to be 0
  geod.2003 <- geodist(fdi.net.2015, inf.replace = NA)
  # The length of the shortest path for all pairs of nodes.
  geod.2003$gdist 
  # The number of shortest path for all pairs of nodes.
  geod.2003$counts  
  # Shortest Path Matrix
  dist_mat = geod.2003$gdist
  hist(dist_mat)
  diam <- max(dist_mat, na.rm = T) # 6
  apl <- mean(dist_mat, na.rm = T)
# (Adapted from https://dnac.ssri.duke.edu/rlabs/2017/02_descriptive_statistics.php)

# REPLICATE WITH IGRAPH
detach(package:sna)
detach(package:network)
library(igraph)
fdi.graph.2003 <- graph_from_data_frame(fdi.edge.2003, directed = T, vertices = fdi.attr.2003)
diam2 <- diameter(fdi.graph.2003, directed = TRUE, unconnected = TRUE) #7
identical(diam, diam2)  # FALSE

# Using intergraph
library(intergraph)
fdi.graph.2003.int <- asIgraph(fdi.net.2003)
class(fdi.graph.2003.int)  # igraph
diam3 <- diameter(fdi.graph.2003.int, directed = TRUE, unconnected = TRUE) #6
identical(diam, diam3)  # TRUE
```

This is only an example. Other and much more relevant problems arose when computing the clique census: the, according to the 'network' class object, I got maximal cliques of size 8. Conversely, with 'igraph' I got a maximal clique of 17!

Any Idea about what is going on?

Comment: This is a fairly broad question and thus hard to answer. Can you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Dear HFBrowning, I could not provide a fully reproducible example. I edited the post including some pieces of code to show what i meant to say in my original (and i recognise it to be slightly cryptical) question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this is coming late, and I hope you've already found an answer! Connections--a journal produced by the International Network for Social Network Analysis--had an article identifying discrepancies between various packages for the same measures. You can find it here: https://www.exeley.com/connections/doi/10.21307/connections-2017-002

I'm new to SNA, so I don't mean to presume to be an expert, but I'd use caution when trying to find the "correct" result. Indegree and outdegree are straightforward and should come out the same regardless of package. My understanding, though, is that clique, cluster, etc. are more nebulous, and the best measure will depend to a certain degree on the research question.

Take that for what it's worth, but I'd recommend ensuring the basic network structure is consistent--edges, indegree, outdegree shouldn't differ between packages--and then decide which package's approach is most relevant to your study.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @Gary DeYoung. Yes, I did solve the issue, but you put it very clearly! Best,